# Can the Linux Kernel run on a processor that can't execute code out of RAM?

Tags: linux-kernel

Running code exclusively in ROM has some security benefits and I was wondering if anything in the Linux kernel requires the ability to run code in RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not directly possible.

But you can start a normal process and then map some ROM ranges into the process space (maybe via device driver depending how the ROM is mapped) and then run code in this mapped range.